# Why am I in danger of being blocked?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
>   you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a
>   good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

As of this moment, I only asked 6 questions, 1 migrated, one got 2 upvotes,  and 3 didn't get any upvotes 0.

1 closed question with -1 I deleted it, why I see this warning? is only 1 closed question enough to ban me?

Comment: This was a recently introduced for sites where there is an automatic question block to warn user when they were getting close to that block. I'm asking to see why it's firing on our site where we don't have the question block enabled.

Comment: @ChrisF okay keep me updated please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning has been turned on network wide, but the block has only been turned on on a few - Web Apps **wasn't** one of them (at the time of writing). On the sites where the block *is* enabled, it's not a final warning but a "hey, pay attention you need to change how you ask questions" message. If you take note of what we're trying to tell you an improve your questions then you'll be more likely to get answers to your questions in the future.

Just because the automatic block isn't enabled doesn't mean you can ignore this.

The automatic blocks have [now been turned on network wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291142/21960)

Comment: but come on! 1 deleted with -1 is enough to warn me?! I'm not even close to being banned unless the rules have changed, besides, what happened to penalty box? I should enter the box, and banning me should be the last option on the table...

Comment: @Fischer - I don't know what the rules are so I can't comment on how severe or lax they are, but I would suspect that it's the totally of your questions not just any that are negative or deleted that's taken into account.

Comment: I just saw this message when I logged into the site.  I haven't asked or answered any questions yet!

Comment: @rossmcm - are you sure about that? I can see two deleted questions.

Comment: Automated blocks have now been turned on network wide. See: [Comprehensive question quality blocks now enabled everywhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291142/21960)