# What specifically about my 3 WebApps questions is causing me to get blocked?

Tags: discussion

> Similar: [Why am I in danger of being blocked?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2656/why-am-i-in-danger-of-being-blocked)

You have reached your question limit
It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon!

> You've asked 4 questions recently, **some of which have not been
>   received very well by the community**. Everyone learns at their own
>   pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your
>   questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account
>   from asking questions entirely.
>
> It's been 1 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you
>   wait 3 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your
>   previous questions, **editing to address any issues that folks have
>   pointed out in comments.**

What specifically about my 3 WebApps questions is causing me to get blocked?

[Reached Limit of max number of people & Pages to See First. What is the limit & how to trim list?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91535/facebook-reached-limit-of-maximum-number-of-people-and-pages-to-see-first-what)

[Way to search Airbnb by Monthly Price & Amenities with Open location?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86301/way-to-search-airbnb-by-monthly-price-amenities-with-open-location)

Moved from SuperUser:

[Advanced Power Search & Filter of Amazon product data & description beyond Books?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/84964/advanced-power-search-filter-of-amazon-product-data-description-beyond-books)

**Update:** 
Auto Deleted - Don't know why

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90592/diskcompare-com-replacement-web-app-service-to-compare-active-recent-storage-d

Also, I never understood why that was deleted. It was a WebApp / Service that aggregated Disk Storage & Pricing data. 
Similar to PriceGrabber etc, but focussed on Storage. It's not updated anymore so I asked if there was an updated WebApp/ Service of that sort

Answer (score 7):

So, you have 4 questions (1 deleted) with a grand total of 1 upvote and 2 downvotes.<sup>1</sup> (The 2 downvotes are on the deleted question.) That's not a great track record. It's not terrible, though, so an upvote on any of your remaining questions will *probably* remove the warning.<sup>2</sup>

Your deleted question was closed because it's off-topic. We no longer accept questions that ask us "to recommend or find a Web Application".<sup>3 4</sup> I expect it was downvoted also because it's off-topic. It was automatically deleted because it was closed for more than 9 days and:

> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days

(Detailed in the [Help Center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).)

As previously mentioned, deleted questions *also* count against you when the quality check looks at your past "performance" when it evaluates whether you should be warned, restricted, or banned from posting.

So, I think you're right on the cusp; one upvote should get you out of the trouble you're in. As long as you continue creating quality content you shouldn't have any further issues.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> At least, at the time this was written. The "Meta effect" may come into play.
<sup>2</sup> The actual algorithm is kept secret, even from Moderators. This is to prevent people from doing "just enough" to keep from being banned.
<sup>3</sup> See the [Help Center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for what's on-topic, and what isn't.
<sup>4</sup> This question *may* be acceptable at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but you'll almost certainly need to provide more details. See their [Help Center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details on what they want in a question.
<sup>5</sup> You may find this useful: [How do I write a great question?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3857/how-do-i-write-a-great-question)

Comment: "We no longer accept" - So, webapps used to accept such requests before - Am I right on that - Then why penalize me for having seen such Qs before? And is this now on topic for Software Recs - do they accept requests for all platforms; web, ios, android, windows, mac, linux?

Comment: How do these apply now: 
http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/double-standards-on-web-app-recommendation-questions?rq=1 

http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2595/make-all-recommendation-questions-out-of-scope-and-off-topic-regardless-of-rese?lq=1

Comment: How about someone undo the negative damage I get by reseting and moving that off topic question to Software Recs with "Web App" tag as suggested here: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/a/2695/35071

Comment: @AIE - I am still getting the same blocked message for no fault of mine. If anything that question could/ should have been moved to Software Recs - Can someone undo the damage so that I can post a fresh question?

Comment: That question is very unlikely to be migrated. It's already deleted; it's essentially no longer here. Migration is also (supposed to be) reserved for excellent questions that just happen to be on the wrong site. Even if you could convince a Moderator to undelete, re-open, and then migrate the question, your status wouldn't change because "migrated" also means "closed", and even if not deleted right away, the migration stub will eventually be deleted, and you'd be in exactly the same situation. Your best bet is to follow the advice here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/

Comment: AI E - Read it, I cant do anything about the 1 bad dead apple. The other 3 seem fine as they're focused and complete - Can you suggest any way to improve them? This is like a "deadlock" as I cannot fix or improve anything from my end.

Comment: I seem to recall you had one question with a "tag" in the title. Surely there are things that can be improved; fixing grammar, making examples more illustrative, making the question "more generic" so that it's useful to other people looking for a solution. There are other ways to contribute. Write useful answers. Make useful edits. You might also consider "accepting" some answers you've received ([help](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)); it might attract more upvoters.

Comment: You might also request that that question that seems to be dragging you down be "disassociated" from your account. ([more information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239366)) Moderators can't do that, so you'd have to contact the development team. (Use the [contact us](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page.) If they agree, that'll probably get you out of the hole you're in, but you can still get yourself in there with poorly-received content in the future.

Comment: @AI E - Which one has Tag in title? There is nothing generic about the Qs - 1. Facebook limit - Will accept answer after trying it out 2 & 3 - Doing Adv Power search on AirBnB & Amazon that is currently not facilitated - Nothing much I can do to this. 4. Deleted post that caused it all - Gone.

Comment: "Facebook:" is an in-title tag. It's redundant, because the most popular tag in the question is already added to the `title` element and is displayed in search results. More information here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging