# What are the criteria for 'some of your questions have not been well received' warnings?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Similar question to this one:

[Why am I in danger of being blocked?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2656/why-am-i-in-danger-of-being-blocked)

I was actually blocked for some months.  During that time I spent several hours going through my questions, my answers, trying to fix them up. I've read the 'how to ask a good question' and so on. Nothing worked.

At present I'm still getting a warning.

At the same time, when I looked at my stats, I see a "You've received a new privilege.

The original event happened on two sites simultaneously, WebApps and SuperUser. For a while I thought I'd been banned from SE entirely.  I think it was triggered by a question that was moved from SU to WA or vice versa.

I've attached a screenshot of my summary page.

How can I find out what is still triggering this warning?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Question ban and answer ban is a separate ban also only affects per-site (e.g. on WA only), not network-wide. All of your posts history are counted, including downvoted/closed/deleted posts (if there were), so you might be still getting this warning even though your recent posts got upvoted. It is to indicate to be very careful when posting the next one from getting downvoted/closed/deleted so that you won't get the automatic post ban again. The exact algorithm is hidden to prevent from being gamed. You might request mods to list your deleted posts in case some of them can be salvaged.

Comment: Related [Comprehensive question quality blocks now enabled everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291142/289691)

Answer (score 3):

Question bans (or blocks) happen on a per-site basis, which means (as you've found out) you can ask here on Meta for help fixing specific questions if you have one. If you're only at risk of being blocked from asking questions, you'll still be able to ask, but will get a warning while doing so. There is no one post that's causing either of these but the combined reception of all of your questions. (And the exact algorithm is a secret kept even from mods.)

The main way to get out of a question ban is to improve your questions until they are more positively received (not deleted, not closed, with as much score as possible). You'll also get the chance to ask a question every six months in spite of being blocked, which you should use as an opportunity to ask a stellar question that will help you get out of it.

If you're not blocked, write stellar questions anyway. And if you can improve your old questions, do that too.

Here are some links to your poorly received questions:

- [Your deleted questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current) (these may have the biggest impact, since they are often also closed or downvoted)
- [Your low-scoring questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20is%3Aq%20score%3A..0)
- [Your closed questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20is%3Aq%20closed%3Ayes)

(These links are to the questions posted by whoever clicks on them, not just for OP.)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the following question is too broad for Web Applications

[How to deal with online position errors in Alberta Rural Addressing system in Google Maps, Bing Maps, Apple Maps, Waze Maps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/126884/88163)

> How to deal with online position errors in Alberta Rural Addressing system in Google Maps, Bing Maps, Apple Maps, Waze Maps

If you have other question like it, that could be one of the reasons to get the warning.